# wordpress - orderby query by "type" is not working?

Tags: php, sql-order-by, wordpress, custom-type

i am trying to query a list in a specific post type order but it doesn't work.

```
$args = array(              
                'post_type' => array('a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' =>  ''.$term_list.''
                            ),
                        ),
                'orderby' => 'type'

                );
```

what's wrong? it works great with 'rand' and other query string but 'type' doesn't seems to be enough!

thanks!

Comment: Order by post type is available since Version 4.0, maybe you are using an older WP version.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've got this working was to filter pre_get_posts. I haven't dug into core to really see what gets set, but the filter does work.

```
function my_search_filter( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_search() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'page','case-study','office', 'career', 'event') );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'type');
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter' );
```

Comment: thank for your help :)
how can i use this filter thru my template file hence i have different type order according a tpl ?

Comment: Which template/WordPress function are you using?

Comment: i am using wp_query function.

Comment: <?php
    $args = array(       
    'post_type' => array('a','b','c','d','e'),
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  ''.$term_list.''
                ),
            ),
    'orderby' => 'type'
    );
     $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();`
    ?>

Comment: from scratch theme :)

Comment: What template are you running this query in?

Comment: aw, sorry! twenty Fourteen's!

Comment: Right. but what template name specifically? index.php, category.php, etc. Knowing this will help hook into the correct page.

Comment: it's a duplicate custom template of single.php

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's a single view of a custom post type. You could do something like this:

```
function my_single_filter( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_singular('custom_post_type_slug') ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('a','b','c','d','e') );
        $query->set( 'orderby', array( 
        array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', 
               'field' => 'slug', 
               'terms' => ''.$term_list.'' ), 
        ));
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'type');
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_single_filter' );
```

This would go in your functions.php file. You will have to get the data via functions.php for the $term_list variable. In your single.php file you can place the default loop.

Comment: big thanks, but i can't make it work, this is really weird...

how can i parse my function to my tpl file?

i tried to put an array to orderby, doesn't work either :(